# Spring: Inject initialized RestTemplates

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Currently I have several services making requests to other services.

In order to build the requests I'm using Spring `RestTemplate`s.

Is there anyway to inject a RestTemplate initialized with some headers...?

I was thinking about Factory injectors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create an interceptor that writes the headers and just inject that configured `Resttemplate` or build in your class once at startup and re-use.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor

Comment: it's all how you declare it in your config class

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching the problem incorrectly.

Instead of injecting a `RestTemplate`,
consider injecting an `HttpEntity<?>`.

Setup the `HttpEntity<?>` bean in your configuration `@Bean` method.

Then use which ever `RestTemplate.exchange()` method is appropriate to send your desired request.

**Edits**
The `exchange` method sends an HTTP message and returns the response.

Here is the [RestTemplate JavaDoc Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)

Comment: What I want to get is to inject current jwt in Authorization header... By other hand, what's `exchange` meant for?